# PostgreSql with Meteor.Js

Tags: database, postgresql, meteor

I need to create a postgreSQL database in meteor.js web app and then fetch data from CSV file and store in it. 
I have no idea how to do that, kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is PostgreSQL driver, check this link https://meteor-postgres.readthedocs.io/en/latest

I recommend you to look into GraphQL, especially Apollo client.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor internally uses MongoDb so I think you will not be able to use PostgreSQL with Meteor. It would be better if you use MongoDb with your meteor based app.